# Which identical image appears in each of these editions' DMGs?

Tags: dnd-3e, prestige-class, adnd-1e, adnd-2e, art

The just-for-fun prestige class [conventioneer](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/cc/20010420a) (or, if that doesn't work for you, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101175831/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/cc/20010420a)) that was posted on Wizards of the Coast Web site in 2001 possesses the special ability convention savvy. The special ability allows a conventioneer to pick, among others, the specialty obscure knowledge, that, in part, says, "Conventioneers know things like which image in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* has shown up in all three editions."

I know I'm a little bit late to the party here, but is there *really* an image that's appeared in the [adnd](/questions/tagged/adnd), [adnd-2e](/questions/tagged/adnd-2e), and [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e) *Dungeon Master's Guides*? If so, what image is it?

---

***Bonus:*** The article's About the Author section lists as one of Matt Smith's possessions a picture of Torg waving "Hi." Who or what is Torg? Or is this a Matt Smith inside joke thing? (Note that this is likely unrelated to the [Torg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torg) *role-playing game—that'd be one* weird *picture—and that the author is probably not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Smith_(actor)) nor [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_(American_band)) Matt Smith—although I'm sure the author's a great guy, too.)*

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I'll comment on the aside: I'm guessing it's a reference to Torg (ALL HAIL KING TORG!) of [KAMB!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobolds_Ate_My_Baby!)

Comment: Actually, since the article's from 2001, the potential image should probably be looked for first within the 2000 printing of the DMG... (now if I could only *find* mine)

Comment: First step would be to compare the list of credited artists. If there's no overlap then odds are slim.

Comment: Is that the literal text from the class? I ask because it seems general enough to admit an answer along the lines of "the D&D logo". I lack the sources to verify either the text or the hypothetical images.

Comment: Although the title of this question says "identical" images, the referenced text doesn't stipulate that the images are strictly identical, as opposed to similar renditions of the same scene. Suggest removing "identical" from the title.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Yet *Which image appears in each of these editions' DMGs?* would be equally misleading. I stand by *identical.* *Identical* — like *opaque*, *unique*, and *vague* — need not be an utter and complete absolute like *square*.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ok, that's your call - in which case I must ask, is the currently most-upvoted answer correct then? And if not, what would be your criteria for an acceptable answer?

Comment: @MarkBeadles It does, indeed, seem correct. Let me go ahead and mark that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That picture is **a warrior trapped in a flooding room while attacked from behind by a skeleton**. It appears in separate depictions by different artists in AD&D 1st edition, AD&D 2nd edition, and D&D 3.0:

- AD&D 1st edition DMG (1979), page 68. David S. La Force
- AD&D 2nd edition revised DMG (1995), page 95.
- D&D 3.0 DMG (2000), page 114. Wayne Reynolds. Captioned "A water trap threatens to quench Alhandra's life."

Comment: I'm certain readers would find the actual illustrations more persuasive than the page numbers, so [I asked over on Meta if including the illustrations is okay](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7695/8610).

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to include those images, should the consensus allow adding these images.

Comment: I would argue that those are _similar scenes_, not the _same image_, but …
 meh.

Comment: I'm moderately confident that this is the 'same image' that the original question refers to. If only I could've found my 3e DMG... +1

Comment: For me, the signature on the D&D 3.0 image seems to include a year (2000). Also, I don't have anything similar in my AD&D 2nd DMG from 1993...

Answer (score 5):

The DMG 1e (Efreet cover, Dec `79) has these artist credits:

> David C. Sutherland III
>   D.A. Trampier
>   Darlene Pekul
>   Will McLean
>   David S. La Force
>   Erol Otus

The DMG 2e (dragon & wizard cover, Nov `92) has these artist credits:

> Jeff Easley
>   Clyde Caldwell
>   John & Laura Lakey
>   David Dorman
>   Douglas Chaffee
>   Jean E. Martin

The DMG 2e Revised (humanoids cover, April `95) has these artist credits:

> Jeff Easley
>   Ned Dameron
>   Laura Lakey
>   Les Dorscheid
>   Dana Knutsøn
>   Roger Loveless
>   David O. Miller
>   Alan Pollack
>   Robh Ruppel

**... so, odds are not good that there is an illustration that has appeared in both 1e and 2e DMGs, let alone survived into the 3e and 3.5e DMGs.**

Comment: Just to be clear, like Chemus's comment on his answer says, it's entirely possible that the similar image may have a different artist in a different edition. That is, the image may depict the same event yet reimagined for the game's then-current iteration.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Then the images are not technically identical. Or the artist credits are not full, or the image was "recreated" to a point where it looks almost the same -- again, not completely identical then. One of the artists could, however, change their name.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I used the word *identical* only in the question's title for convenience. If you'd like to soften that word to something less absolute, feel free to edit the title. (Also, many English words that *appear* to be absolutes *technically* aren't absolutes—although I wouldn't use the commonplace comparative or superlative of identical (*identicaler* and *identicalist* being crimes against language), *more identical* is okay, as is *opaquer* & *opaquest*, [*uniquer*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7441) & *uniquest*, and *vaguer* & *vaguest*. O, man. Sorry! Lecture mode: off.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Lecture mode is OK, but *identicaler* and *uniquest*... Not a native speaker here, but *identical* sounds like an absolute, two entities are either 100% identical or they are not. Maybe I am wrong, though.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy (Like I mentioned, *identicaler* would be a language crime, but a sentence like *There are two pairs of identical twins, but the Jones twins are more identical than the Smith twins* is how one could employ the *actual* comparative form of *identical.* In much the same way one could say *Yeah, those* DMG *images are identical, but they're not as identical as I'd like them to be.* And *uniquest* is a great and perfectly cromulent *Scrabble* word. `;-)`)

Answer (score 3):

Having leafed through my 1979 *Dungeon Masters Guide* [adnd](/questions/tagged/adnd), 1989 *Dungeon Master's Guide* [adnd-2e](/questions/tagged/adnd-2e) and 2003 *Dungeon Master's Guide* [dnd-3.5](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5), I find no images that are even markedly similar, let alone identical.

So, unless there's something I've missed, or the images are in printings that I don't have access to (later editions of the AD&D DMG, or AD&D 2e DMG, or in my misplaced 2000 *Dungeon Master's Guide* [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e)), there appear to be *no* identical images that span all three editions.

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote you for it or nothin'—in fact, seriously, thanks for looking!—, but since the *DMG* underwent the most serious surgery during the *3.5* revision, it's entirely possible there's an illustration in the *DMG* for *3e* that's absent from the *DMG* for *3.5e.* (I mean, the illo'd also have to be in the *DMG*s for *AD&D* and *AD&D 2e*, but still.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well, I've since been able to examine a different printing of the AD&D DMG, as well as the revised 2e DMG, and the closest they have to having the 'same image' as the article states is that 1e and 2e revised have a, differently illustrated, scene of a man apparently trapped in a water-filled chamber with a sword wielding skeleton. Also, it says "which image in the Dungeon Master's Guide has shown up in all three editions", not that it's in the earlier editions' DMG's. I think this may be a bit ox an X Y problem.

Comment: O, *damn*, dude.  That's not an XY problem, but me misunderstanding the precision the trivia requires. Go forth and challenge that frame!